# Azure Data Flow - CSV to Parquet files - with updating files

Tags: azure, csv, parquet, azure-data-factory

I am currently trying to convert weekly CSV files to yearly Parquet files via Azure Synapse Data Flow. But if a new CSV file is uploaded or an existing CSV-file is being modified, the yearly Parquet-file is being overwritten with only the data of the new or modified csv file. What should happen is, that only the new or modified data should be inserted into the corresponding yearly parquet file and the old data should still exist.
[image]
My current Data Flow has it's source on the folder that contains the CSV-files. Enable change data capture is enabled. After that, the dataset is filtered and then grouped year and saved to sink. Grouping is done by adding a Column in step "GroupByYear" which contains the full path to the file (**/2022.parquet) and is generated by another column in the dataset which contains a datetime.
[image]
The column is then used in the sink as the "File name option"
[image]

The result looks like the following:

[image]

If a new csv file was added to the source or a file has been modified, the data flow should alter the corresponding Parquet-file and add the new data, not overwrite it with only the new data.